# Not a Valid Method Expression when combine view.viewId in action attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, mojarra

I use a common JSF template for multiple views. It contains data picker controls for entering data range and a button for refreshing the current view.

I am utilizing Post/Redirect/Get pattern so I am appending `?faces-redirect=true` attribute to the navigation.

In JSF 2.1 (Mojarra) it was sufficient to refresh the page using 

`<h:commandButton action="?faces-redirect=true" value="submit"/>`

In JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.12) this doesn't seem to be valid any more (I am getting something like this [strange "String index out of range: 0" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379693/strange-string-index-out-of-range-0-error)) and the current view has to be specified as well:

`<h:commandButton action="index?faces-redirect=true" value="submit"/>`

To make this link dynamic I've tried to utilize `view.viewId` variable:

`<h:commandButton action="#{view.viewId}?faces-redirect=true" value="submit"/>`

However, this construct returns `Not a Valid Method Expression` error. Btw, that `view.viewId` returns `/index.xhtml`, which works fine when hardcoded instead of that variable.

Surprisingly, if that `view.viewId` is used without that 'suffix' part, it works:

`<h:commandButton action="#{view.viewId}" value="submit"/>`

Any idea how to fix this for JSF 2.2?